# Publish ASPX to sub directory of application [Cannot Load Type]

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, iis, web-config

I have published an asp.net application to a sub directory of my IIS application. I know that the web.config must exist at the root for several of the properties to work. So I have moved my web.config to the root of the application. I get the following error:

```
Could not load type 'ProjectName.myTypeName'.
```

I suspect that not having the web.config in the same directory as this aspx file is causing the issue. How do I config this so that my web.config can live in the root while the aspx file lives where I need it to?

Thanks!

-Nick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The application loads types from the /bin directory at the root of the web application.  If your types are not in that directory, it won't be able to create instances of them. You have a few options:

1. Create an application/virtual directory from the sub-directory.
2. Move the required assemblies to the /bin directory of the main application.
3. Add your sub directory to the probing path of the application.

Comment: The assemblies have to be in the root as well - at least this works best for my project. Thank you sir.

Answer (score 0):

Check that the `dll` it is looking for exists in the website `bin` directory and is of the correct version.

Answer (score 0):

Make the subdirectory a virtual directory and keep your web.config in the subdirectory